Writing/Reading from a binary file without having to declare a buffer variable - but via anonymous object
Currently, for writing to a binary file I'd write:
file.write((char*)&toWrite, sizeof(toWrite type));

And for reading from a binary file I'd write:
file.read((char*)&readInto, sizeof(readInto type));

But because of this method of reading/writing, presetting default values to a binary file (for insequential-reading/writing from/to the file) would require the use of a buffer variable with default values:
myType defaultValues; //defaultValues is initialized with
//myType's default constructor values
file.write((char*)&defaultValues, sizeof(myType));

I thought that via an anonymous object it would be possible in the following, shorter, form:
file.write((char*)&myType(), sizeof(myType)); //myType() is 
//an object which is initialized by myType's default constructor values

But because anonymous object's are not lvalues it's impossible.
Hence, the question is: Is there a way to shorten - by omitting the need to define a variable solely for the presetting of a binary file - the presetting of a binary file like I've done with anonymous object - just in a way that would actually work?

What exactly is the goal here? You'd like to add sizeof(myType) bytes to your binary file? Are those bytes required to form some valid myType instance, or maybe you can just push sizeof(myType) zeroes?

The goal is to add sizeof(myType) bytes to the binary file, and these bytes should be the bytes that form myType defaultValues

@CSStudent I think what the other comment is getting at is that you never mentioned (in the text) that myType has a default constructor that initializes the object to (non-zero) default values. If my guess is accurate, the idea is that you might want to change these values via the constructor's definition and have the change be reflected in the file. If so, this would be good to mention, as it gives your code some motivation.


Currently, for writing to a binary file I'd write:
file.write((char*)&toWrite, sizeof(toWrite type));


Let me interrupt the question at this point to note that this is a bit redundant. The second parameter is completely determined by the first, so why should you have to write it out? Let's create a wrapper template for this to shorten your code. (It's up to what namespace this should go in, or maybe you want to give it a less-common name.)
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
requires std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>
void write(std::ostream& out, const T& data) {
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&data), sizeof(T));
}

Now your writes are more simply
     write(file, toWrite);

Note: The requires clause ensures that this template is used only when it is safe to do so. For example, this is not a safe way to write a std::string. Having the compiler check this is a benefit of this template. Other caveats for this approach still apply; it is not guaranteed to be portable across systems.
Okay, let's get back to your question.

But because anonymous object's are not lvalues it's impossible.

Hmm... strange, but this is no longer a problem... Did I sabotage your question?

The requires clause ought to be requires std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>. For any other types it will have undefined behavior straight away. And even for trivially-copyable types the result written to the file will not be portable in any way and reading it back will only be guaranteed to work on the same system as it was written.

@user17732522 Thanks. I no longer have "lazy" as an excuse :) so I've updated the answer.

Thanks, but why is requires std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> required?

@CSStudent "why is requires std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> required?" -- This is worthy of being its own question, rather than being lost in a comment. See How can I know if a variable can be written directly into a binary file? for some background info.

@JaMiT -- Thanks!

It should be acceptable to explicitly cast the temporary value to a reference, which guarantees that its lifetime will be extended until the end of the full-expression. Then, you can take the adress of that value via that reference:
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&static_cast<int const&>(int())), sizeof(int));

Substitute int for your myType.

But it has 100% exactly the same meaning as the solution with a named variable in all regards. There is no benefit to doing it this way. It just makes the code less readable.

@user17732522 oh yeah, I totally agree. However, I believe that this is exactly what the used has asked. They asked if it's possible to omit the separate declaration of a variable. Whether that's good code is up for debate. I would not code it that way, but nonetheless I believe it's beneficial to be aware that this could be achieved in the presented way
